# facebook Graph update,modify the android application side?

Tags: android, facebook

Currently, we are using facebook Graph api update V 2.6 with android application.
I am planning to change the version from 2.6 to 3.0, but do I need to modify the application side?

With API Upgrade Tool on WEB,

When selected as follows

Upgrade from:
v2.6
Upgrade to: 
v3.0

Result
"Your app has no changes for the methods you selected between v2.6 and v3.0"

Comment: i also have this issue needs to update to 3.0

Comment: have you manage to update ?